# Multiple cross tabs in single jasperreports and grouping them

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Can anyone please tell me how to group crosstabs w.r.t report level group. i.e. in my problem i am using three crosstabs in details band.....and i want this page to be grouped by coutryname. eg.if `country=Australia` print three crosstabs and if country changes to india print three crosstab on the next page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subdataset for your Crosstab, which take the country as parameter.

In the main report, call for a list of the country you want to display. This will produce one detail band for each country (ex: `$F{Country}`)

In the detail band use the value of the country field (`$F{Country}`) as parameter for the subdataset you use in your cross tab.